# How to exclude elements from css selection

Tags: css

I have this CSS:

```css
.post-content a {
  text-decoration:none !important;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #75d54f!important;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -4px 0 #75d54f;
  color: inherit;
  transition: background 0.1s cubic-bezier(.30,.60,.60,1);
}

.post-content a:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -4px 0 #75d54f!important;
  color: inherit !important;
  transition: background 0.1s cubic-bezier(.30,.60,.60,1) !important;
  background:#75d54f;
}
```

This applies styling to all `a` elements inside a wordpress post. Now there are certain `a` elements that I don't want to get that styling. How can I exclude them?

Some have a class defined (Eg. `<a class="jp-relatedposts-post-a"`) and others don't, but more likely have a parent element with a class defined so I could use that.

Bottomline, how can I exclude certain a elements using their class(or id's) or their parent's class

For now I'm adding this for a solution:

```css
#toc_container a {
  border-bottom: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  color: inherit !important;
  transition: none !important;
  background:transparent;
}

#toc_container a:hover {
  border-bottom: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  color: inherit !important;
  transition: none !important;
  background:transparent;
}
```

but for some elements, this solution will mess up things as others might just need some of those attributes. This one for example, `.et_pb_promo_button et_pb_button` needs a `border-bottom`.

Answer (score 0):

Open the dev tools.

In the `DOM`, find the element you want to style.

`Right click > Copy > Copy selector`.

Now paste it into your `CSS` file and it will be only applied to **that element**, to the specific parent `<div>`.

You will get the full path to the element. `div > div > div:nth-child(2) > a` **for example**.

This is just an example.

```
body > header > .someclass > div > div:nth-child(2) > a {
 color: #000;
}
```

This will only apply to anchor that is within `header` on a specific element, just one element.

Comment: Well, I don't want to apply that style to certain a elements but to all and only exclude those I don't want to be styled. The reason here is that the excluded elements are always the same but the a-styled elements could be different every time in a wordpress post. See this unreviewed website version here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47242479/revisions

Comment: I'm afraid that that's not possible. You will need to modify every element individually. `a { color: #000 }` gives every `<a>` the color of **black**, but if you want to style some `<a>` and exclude some `<a>`, there is no other way to do that, but manually.

Comment: Manual is fine as long I can exclude them all by using a parent's class but this `.entry-content a:not(#toc_container > p > span > a) {
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0px #0DBE98;
}` for some reason doesn't work

Comment: That's not my answer. Don't use `a:not` and parentheses. Use `<a>` without `:not` suffix and parentheses. Use `:not` when you advance in programming, not as a beginner since you don't yet fully understand what it means. For now, use the basic **CSS selector** and as time passes by, you will advance and you will write professional code, but start with basics.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the :not selector (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

So for example if you want to exclude all elements with the class "jp-relatedposts-post-a" from the default formatting, you could do:

```
.post-content a:not(.jp-relatedposts-post-a) {
```